# binarySearch function error

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AnotherArrayPractice{
public static void main (String[] args){
  int [] arr={130,10};
  System.out.println(arr[1]);
  System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr,10));
  System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr,130));

  }
}
```

The print result is as follow: 10, -1, 0. 
I am confused as to why the `binarySearch(arr,10)` gives me `-1` while in fact `10` is inside the array

Answer (score 4):

As you can read from documentation:

> The java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key) method searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the binary search algorithm.The array must be sorted before making this call.If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

So you **must** order the array before!

Instead if you use not sorted, the results are **undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

"The array must be sorted"

as per binarySearch specification